# Flutter App crashes emulator when opening camera

Tags: android, macos, flutter, virtual-device-manager

I am trying to build a bar code scanner app in Flutter. For this, I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan) plugin. I added it to `pubspec.yaml`, modified the `AndroidMainfest.xml` file and added the simple code as below:

```
Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      var qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      result = qrResult as String;
    } catch (ex) {
//      result = "Unknown Error $ex";
    }
  }
```

The above method is invoked on a button press. So the app loads and I click the button, the whole emulator crashes without any logs or error message. Here is the [whole logcat](https://pastebin.com/Cn10n7p2) I recorded during the flow. In the end, it says

```
2020-04-19 20:20:21.285 1740-2027/? I/Camera2ClientBase: Camera 0: Opened. Client: io.yeshwanthvshenoy.addup (PID 4260, UID 10086)
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/i7SGjTnv) is another log from the default camera app. I can't seem to find out why this is happening. My emulator settings are all default, I didn't change any setting except the back camera one which is set to `Webcam0`. The possible options where `virtual scene`, `none`, `emulated` and `webcam0`. Is it maybe that my Mac is not giving permissions to AVD to access camera? How can I check that if so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulators don't have camera, so you need to avoid executing your code on simulators. Using the [device info](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info) plugin you can get various information about the device you're running on, including `isPhysicalDevice` for both android and iOS.

Comment: so basically I can't use camera on virtual device even connecting to webcam??

Comment: Unfortunately no, you need physical device for that.

Comment: This is an old question, but in the interest of accuracy, you can absolutely use the camera of your device while using an emulator.